# Create environment file on docker build

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Environments files are in git ignore just because of confidential info so I need create those angular environments file while building docker image.

I am getting the below error while running the docker build.

```
an unhandled exception occurred: The /usr/src/app/ng/src/environments/environment.prod.ts path in file replacements does not exist.
```

Docker file

```
FROM node:16 AS ng-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY frontend/ ./frontend/
RUN cd frontend && npm install --legacy-peer-deps && npm run build --aot --output-hashing=none

FROM node:16 AS node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY backend/ ./backend/
COPY --from=ng-build /usr/src/app/frontend/dist/ ./backend/public
RUN cd backend && npm ci --only=production --omit=dev && npm cache clean --force
COPY backend/server.js ./backend/
 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./backend/server.js"]
```

Please suggest to me the right way to achieve it.

Comment: I see you're serving your app via Node. Why not just pass what you need for the environment from the server side via environment variables and pick them up from a service in Angular to pass to components?

Comment: Can you please provide some code samples?
I am new to this.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It's pretty simple. Pass a JSON stringified object to your index.html which you'll set in session storage. Then have a service retrieve the session storage data, parse it back to an object and provide it as a property.